# Two-sided closed ideals of $C(X,M_2(\mathbb C))$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be compact and Hausdorff space. I know all closed ideals of $C(X)$.
 I want to substitute $\mathbb C$ by $M_2(\mathbb C)$.
What can we say about two-sided closed ideals of $C(X,M_2(\mathbb C))$?

Comment: If it is the trivial field you are considering then write that algebra as $C(X)\otimes M_2$. Is $M_2$ simple?

Comment: Hi.yes.M_2(C)is simple.

Comment: Good. That should then answer your question :)

Comment: You say that we can write C(X)⊗M2 instead of C(X,M2(C))?and closed ideals are same

Comment: Do you mean: closed ideals of C(X)⊗M2(C) and C(X) are the same?

Comment: that is what i mean

Comment: what is the form of closed ideals A⊗B?is it I⊗J such that I is ideal of A and J is ideal of B

Comment: There could be more in general (consider $C([0,1])\otimes C([0,1])\cong C([0,1]^2)$).

Answer (score 1):

You should study Morita equivalence of C*-algebras (in the sense of Rieffel): the fact is that $C(X,M_2)$ is Morita equivalent to $C(X)$. And it is a general fact that Morita equivalent C*-algebras have same closed (two-sided) ideals. It follows that the closed ideals of $C(X,M_2)$ are all of the form $C_0(U,M_2)$ (functions vanishing outside $U$) for $U\subseteq X$.

More generally, you can replace $M_2$ by $M_n$ or even the algebra $K(H)$ of compact operators on some Hilbert space $H$. You can also replace $X$ by a locally compact space (and use $C_0(X)$ instead).

Comment: Dear Buss.I try to study Morita equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier approach is as follows: Let $R$ be any unital commutative ring, then there is a one-to-one correspondence between ideals in $R$ and ideals in $M_2(R)$. In fact, if $J \subset M_2(R)$ is an ideal, then
$$
I = \{a \in R : \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\
0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in J\}
$$
is the corresponding ideal in $R$ such that $J = M_2(I)$. Thus, if $R$ is also a Banach algebra, one can go further and show that if the ideal in $M_2(R)$ is closed, then the corresponding ideal in $R$ must also be closed and vice-versa.

Now you just need to observe that
$$
C(X)\otimes M_2(\mathbb{C}) \cong M_2(C(X))
$$
Thus, every ideal in $C(X)\otimes M_2(\mathbb{C})$ must be of the form
$$
C_0(U)\otimes M_2(\mathbb{C})
$$
for some open set $U \subset X$.

Comment: +1, small typo, the definition of $I$ is missing an $\in J$